# should I make Different id for each banner and Interstitial Ad in Admob

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have **multiple activities** in my application and so **i have multiple banners and interstitial Ads, ** so should I keep **a single publisherID** for all the banners and interstitial ads or ***should I make a different publisher ID for each ad in the application ?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new Admob dashboard publisherId relates to you (your account) and AdUnitId relates to ad spots that you want filled. I'll out my answer in terms of the new dashboard. NB As of Jan-2014 I think the dashboard has been rolled out most places, but there may be some stillw waiting such as India.

I would suggest that you definitely have different adUnitIds for your banner ads versus your interstitials. Whether you want separate adUnits for different Activities within your app is up to you. If you want to track revenue and fill for each of those spots individually then yes.

But unless those spots are radically different in terms of content and user base then I would suggest you go with the simple route and have a single adUnitId per app (two if you are using both banners and interstitials).

Comment: I have doubt again now i have a mediationID as well which one to use ?

should i use mediationID in all banners or on some banners ?

Comment: If your are using the new Admob dashboard then your adUnitId **is** a mediationId. Always use mediation.