# Adding AdMob to project with MobFox SDK currently integrated

Tags: admob, ads, banner-ads, mobfox

I downloaded and integrated the **MobFox** SDK into my app and it works just fine (currently receiving test banners only).

I also have an **AdMob** account and wish to now use AdMob for when I don't receive an ad from MobFox.

I've looked at the MobFox website, but can't find any documentation that explains how this can be achieved.

It doesn't help that I'm new to mobile Ad networks.

I am assuming that I need to set up mediation - do I need to set this up within my MobFox account or within my AdMob account (or both?).

I'm guessing, that as the AdMob mediation with MobFox isn't server-side, I would also have to integrate AdMob's SDK also (I've done this before so shouldn't be a problem) - just not sure how to use *both* in a project that already has the MobFox SDK integrated.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to set up mediation on my MobFox account, AdMob account, or both accounts?

**The mediation setup is done on one of the sites.** It requires you to enter a ID from the other network. You will need accounts on both sites, a "ad unit" on AdMob and a "publication" on MobFox. You have to decide who you would like to do the mediation.

Your specific mediation setup will determine which network has priority in which cases.

> Will I have to integrate <other network>s SDK as well?

For some mediation you will need to include a SDK/adapter. This mostly comes down to including a JAR, adding it to the build path, and then having a couple of changes in your manifest. The code for showing the ad itself remains the same.

- If MobFox is your mediation host: [Adapter/SDK details for AdMob](http://www.mobfox.com/google/)
- If AdMob is your mediation host: [Adapter/SDK details for all networks](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks)

Comment: Thanks @Ondkloss, so as I'm currently using the MobFox SDK in my project and want to use the MobFox network as my primary network and AdMob as my secondary one, I'm guessing that I want to set up AdMob (Including my AdMob ad-unit ID's) within my MobFox control panel and not the other way around.  According to MobFox documentation I don't need to make any changes at all to my code as it's the AdMob adaptor is already integrated into their SDK but I'm not sure.  Have you experience with MobFox?

Comment: I am using AdMob as my primary, with MobFox as a mediation network. I also read about the adapter being included. I think it depends on what version of the SDK you have, but it may very well be included. Also, you said: You will do the setup in you MobFox control panel.

Comment: Thanks @Ondkloss - I have a 1  ad unit set up in AdMob (for banners) and I would like to ad another for an interstitial (I assume that's what I need to do), however, MobFox only allows for 1 ad-unit per app as far as I can tell - have I got this right?  If so, any ideas how I set this up within MobFox (with 2 ad-units?) Cheers

Comment: Interstitials don't require a separate ad unit. You can use the same ID for interstitial that you use for banner ads. The difference is the code you use to show it.

Comment: So when I set up my Ad-Unit in AdMob and it asks me to chose 'banner or interstitial' - are you saying this step is redundant?  I can chose either and then serve either banners or interstitials to it (or both)?  Sorry, I'm new to Advertising and am really confused by this!  Thanks again!

Comment: I see from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921008/should-i-make-different-id-for-each-banner-and-interstitial-ad-in-admob) that this might have changed with the new AdMob. I'm actually not sure how they have planned this to work with mediation!